# How do I distribute answers lacking geo information from a poll?

Tags: spatial, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

My data table looks like this:

```
Region Answer1 Answer2
NaN 20 40
Region1 15 17
Region2 18 19
...
```

So is it possible to distribute answers for which region is not available with some kind of probability?

Programming is not a problem, I know python and also did some plotting R (it was quite a while ago though). Which method I should look up?

Comment: A common solution to the problem of missing data is multiple imputation. As a start, you might begin by reviewing  the questions bearing that tag.

Comment: You should enter into this endeavor fully aware of the possibility that missingness could have a (strong) relationship to the region (and therefore the answers probably should not be uniformly or randomly assigned to the regions). Did you collect, or can you collect, any information bearing on this?

Comment: it was an online poll. And for 1/3 of the participants we don't have their location, most likely because they had geolocation turned off on their devices. So I believe it should be random.